# Bootstrap 4 vertical align text won't center on card

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

Trying to vertically align the text center in the following card:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row text-center h-100">
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center my-auto">
    <div class="card card-block justify-content-center" style="height: 120px">
      <div class="card-body">
        This is some text within a card body.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am fully aware of the many similar questions here, however I tried various solutions and none of them seems to work for my cards.

I tried "my-auto" on parent, card, and card-body. I tried "d-flex align-items-center h-100" and "justify-content-center". Also tried to play around with the display property. What am I missing?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Here is a solution using bootstrap 4 documentation for `flexbox`. Read more [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/)

What you need to know,

`d-flex` -> makes the element a flexbox.

`align-items-center` - vertically aligns the content.

`justify-content-center` - horizontally aligns the content.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row text-center h-100">
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center my-auto">
    <div class="card card-block d-flex" style="height: 120px">
      <div class="card-body align-items-center d-flex justify-content-center">
        This is some text within a card body.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. I missed the d-flex in the card-body, had it previously only in the class card.

Answer (score 4):

> What am I missing?

Line-height :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row text-center h-100">
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center my-auto">
    <div class="card card-block justify-content-center" style="height: 120px; line-height:120px;">
      <div class="card-body">
        This is some text within a card body.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not work for a smaller box when the text has to break.

Answer (score 0):

**By this Way you can align card-title into center.**

```css
 .card-title-center{
        float: none !important;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <div class="card col-12 text-center">
    <div class="card-header bg-secondary">
        <h3 class="card-title card-title-center">Card Title</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```