# Vertical align text in Bootstrap card

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have the following card, I am trying to vertically center align the text "Light card title", I have added `align-middle` but it does not have an effect. How can the text be vertically center aligned?

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

                <div class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;;">
                    <div class="card-header">Total Views</div>
                    <div class="card-body" style=" height:150px">
                        <h5 class="card-title text-center align-middle">Light
                            card title</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Use a table of 1 row and 1 cell and vertical align in a td.

Comment: If you want to use flex, change the classes on your card-body div to `<div class="card-body d-flex flex-column justify-content-center" style=" height:150px;">` That will align the content in the card body to the center.

Comment: like @RichDeBourke suggested .. use flex and  add these classes to the card-body : `d-flex flex-column justify-content-center`  instead of `align-middle`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. In the [Bootstrap 5 document](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/vertical-align/), they have mentioned that to vertically center "non-inline content" (like `<div>`s and more), use our flex box utilities.
With the help of these utilities, you can easily align the text vertically and horizontally center.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;;">
  <div class="card-header">Total Views</div>
  <div class="card-body d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style=" height:150px">
    <h5 class="card-title">Light card title</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are [several different ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388989/) to center align content. Here's a simple method for card content...

```
  <div class="card bg-light mb-3 justify-content-center" style="max-width: 18rem;;">
        <div class="card-header">Total Views</div>
        <div class="card-body d-flex" style="height:150px">
            <h5 class="card-title m-auto">Light card title</h5>
        </div>
  </div>
```

- use `d-flex` for display:flex
- use `m-auto` for auto margins

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/p/fbH7h0ewYw)

Related: [Bootstrap 4 vertical align text won't center on card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46857136/bootstrap-4-vertical-align-text-wont-center-on-card)